# Create a trigger that inserts old values into other table when a row is updated

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers

I'm trying to implement a trigger on a SQL Server database, which will insert a new row in `table2` whenever a row is updated in `table1`. I want to get the row data (`table1`) before update.

For example, I have the following rows:

```
 table1:                          table2:
 ________________________         ________________________
 |  id       |    name  |         |  id    |     name    |
 ________________________         ________________________
 |   1       |    John  |         
 ------------------------
```

Currently I'm using the following trigger-

```
CREATE TRIGGER triggername
ON table1
FOR UPDATE
AS
Begin
  INSERT INTO table2(name) 
     SELECT i.name 
     FROM Inserted i
End
```

This trigger is doing the following -

```
 table1:                          table2:
 ________________________         ________________________
 |  id       |    name  |         |  id    |     name    |
 ________________________         ________________________
 |   1       |    Alex  |         |   1    |      Alex   |
 ------------------------         ------------------------
```

But I want 'John' in table2. For example, table1 and table2 now should be as follows-

```
 table1:                          table2:
 ________________________         ________________________
 |  id       |    name  |         |  id    |     name    |
 ________________________         ________________________
 |   1       |    Alex  |         |   1    |      John   |
 ------------------------         ------------------------
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the `Deleted` pseudo table in your trigger, which contains the **old** values (before the `UPDATE`):

```
CREATE TRIGGER triggername
ON table1
FOR UPDATE
AS
Begin
  INSERT INTO table2(name) 
     SELECT d.name 
     FROM Deleted d
End
```

The `Inserted` pseudo table contains the **new** values - after the `UPDATE`.

Answer (score 1):

This will only return the new value:

```
INSERT INTO table2(name) 
SELECT i.name 
FROM Inserted i
```

This however will return the value before the update

```
INSERT INTO table2(name) 
select d.name
from inserted i
  join deleted d
    on (i.id = d.id)
```

Answer (score 1):

use the following-

```
 Begin
   INSERT INTO table2(name) 
   SELECT d.name 
   FROM Deleted d
 End
```